# The empty menuPopup Window in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

In my application the menu in the actionbar is not rendered correctly. It is all white and the size is not normal. I've tried to change the background and I'm able to see the text, but the shape still is not normal.

[image: The menu]

The menu is working, you can click and
 The blow picture are taken with layout Inspector,

[image: This is a normal menu]

[image: This is what I've got]

I've searched almost everything to get the normal menu, but couldn't find a way.

1. It seems the layout is not correctly inflated.
2. The text color is same as background.

any suggestions?

Sytle

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#AFDDF6</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#9FFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/Black</item>
</style>
```

Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_info"
            android:orderInCategory="200"
            android:title="info"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"/>
</menu>
```

and the dependencies;

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
```

The menu creation

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

On create

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.MainTitle);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
```

XML part related to AppBarLayout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">


        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_topMainActivity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        />

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

The toolbar XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Could you provide a code of how you initialize the actionBar.

Comment: I think, both can help. First of all, I want to understand, do you use a Toolbar or not, and I want to see how you initialize your menu in the activity(or fragment)

Comment: It'd be better if you provided styles ExpandedAppBar and CollapsedAppBar as well.

Comment: ExpandedAppBar  CollapsedAppBar  has no special styles  other than`parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and got similar issue. Then I changed "android:theme" inside **AppBarLayout** to a new one from androidx packages and the text inside menu became visible:

```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary"
      >
```

[image: Your screen]

Is that what you're looking for?

Regarding size, it's default for new styles from androidX. But if you want to have it as it was before, then you need to change parent from

> "parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"

to

> "parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge"

at your *AppTheme* style.

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend making your AppTheme as   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">, as you set toolbar manually.

Comment: To be honest, as you can see, I don't have oversized menu. Probably, it's related to OS version. I'm launching it on Android 9 emulator. Which one do you have?

Comment: Those screenshots are not clear for me. On the first one you have an oversized toolbar, but on the screenshots taken from layout inspector they're bit smaller than on the first one. So, I have an assumption: attribute `showAsAction` is not working properly and menu inflater tries to fit it to the dropdown instead of placing it to the left of the menu button.

Comment: Or are you complaining that the androidX style for toolbar makes it bigger than the old one?

Comment: I think, yes. It seems they added more rounded corners and made it bigger. https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#behavior

Comment: Yes. In your AppTheme change parent from "parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" to "parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge"

Comment: All, perfect. Thanks. And for the award in 19 hours :)